# How to create unnamed PyTorch parameters in state dict?

Tags: python, pytorch, transfer-learning

I am trying to load a model checkpoint (`.ckpt` file) for transfer learning. I do not have the model's source code, so I am trying to recreate it with PyTorch, like this:

```python
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class IngrDetNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IngrDetNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(n_ingr, 1024)
        self.fc2= nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(256, n_ingr)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.leaky_relu(x, 0.2)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.leaky_relu(x, 0.2)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = F.leaky_relu(x, 0.2)
        x = self.fc4(x)
        
        ingrs = F.sigmoid(x)
        return ingrs

# Create a basic model instance
model = IngrDetNet()
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

The syntax is based on [this PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/defining_a_neural_network.html).

Then, I am trying to load in the checkpoint's state dict, based on [this PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_and_loading_a_general_checkpoint.html#load-the-general-checkpoint):

```python
model_path = Path('../Models/PITA/medr2idalle41.ckpt')
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path, map_location=map_loc)['weights_id'])
```

But I get a key error mismatch:

```
Error(s) in loading state_dict for DataParallel:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "module.fc1.weight", "module.fc1.bias", "module.fc2.weight", "module.fc2.bias", "module.fc3.weight", "module.fc3.bias", "module.fc4.weight", "module.fc4.bias". 
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "module.model.0.weight", "module.model.0.bias", "module.model.2.weight", "module.model.2.bias", "module.model.4.weight", "module.model.4.bias".
```

The checkpoint state dict contains indexed keys such as `module.model.0.weight`, whereas my architecture contains named parameters such as `module.fc1.weight`. How do I generate layers in such a way that my parameters are not named but indexed?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there is a full mismatch of the keys is that you are using the [`nn.DataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html) module utility. This means it will wrap your original parent model under a wrapper `"model"` `nn.Module`. In other words:

```
>>> model = IngrDetNet()                  # model is a IngrDetNet
>>> model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)  # model.model is a IngrDetNet
```

This in turn means your initialized model ends up with a prefixed `"model."` in its state dict keys.

---

You can fix this effect by changing the keys yourself before applying them on the model. A *dict* comprehension should do:

```
>>> state = torch.load(model_path, map_location=map_loc)
>>> state = {f'model.{k}': v for k, v in state['weights_id'].items()}

>>> model.load_state_dict(state)
```

Comment: It is actually the other way around: the imported model was using nn.DataParallel, and my model was not, so that's why I applied it to my model as well, as you can see in my code. This means that now both models have keys starting with "module" (not "model"). However, changing the keys of the imported module was a good tip, since I don't need to use nn.DataParallel now anymore and can just get rid of "module", using: {k.replace('module.',''): v for k, v in state['weights_id'].items()}

Comment: in other words, that was not where my problem was coming from, but it still helped, because I didn't realise I can just rename the state dict's keys!